# Return only Google results containing all terms using python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to google sets of authors together and only want to return a result if both names are present.
ex: if you google "colette johnson beatrix smith textbook", the top result says "missing: beatrix" so I would like to return no result.

The below code returns all of the links, but I want to exclude any results that do not contain all 5 words.  How can I go about doing this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search = 'colette+johnson+beatrix+smith+textbook'
results = 10
url = (f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search}&num={results}")
requests_results = requests.get(url)
links = BeautifulSoup(requests_results.content, "html.parser").find_all("a")
for link in links:
        link_href = link.get('href')
        if "url?q=" in link_href and not "webcache" in link_href:
                if len(link.find_all('h3')) > 0:
                    print(link.get('href').split("?q=")[1].split("&sa=U")[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use double quotes `"` surrounding each term. For instance, if I search for `python` and `stackoverflow`, I can type `"python"+"stackoverflow"` in the query, which looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22python%22%2B%22stackoverflow%22&oq=%22python%22%2B%22stackoverflow%22
```

Formatting this into python:

```py
from requests.utils import quote


terms = '+'.join((
     f'"{term}"' for term in 
     'colette+johnson+beatrix+smith+textbook'.split('+')
))


# we want to preserve the '"' like the example
query = quote(terms, safe='"')

r = requests.get(f'https://google.com/search?q={q}&num={results}')
```

## Edit

Turns out the escaping doesn't need to be done, so you can use `params` in the `requests.get` call:

```py
r = requests.get(
    f'https://google.com/search?', 
    params={'q': terms, 'num': results}
)
```

You can also verify your search parameters without executing the search by using the url without the `search` portion:

```py
from requests import Request

params = {
    'q': terms,
    'num': results
}

req = Request(
    'GET', 
    'https://google.com/?', # Note the missing search ahead of ?
    params=params
)

print(req.prepare().url)

https://www.google.com/?q=%22colette%22%2B%22johnson%22%2B%22beatrix%22%2B%22smith%22%2B%22textbook%22&num=3
```

Which you can paste into your browser and see:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought to put quotes around the whole thing and it didn't work, but around each word makes more sense!

Comment: @JohnSmith no problem! Yeah if you put quotes around the whole thing you will explicitly search for 'colette+johnson+...' which won't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Using 'split' and 'change' your query Google, maybe work.

```
search = 'colette johnson beatrix smith textbook'
search_words = search.split()
```

Query google:

```
url = (f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search.replace(' ', '+')}&num={results}")
```

Result:

[Result Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzf2q.png)